# Java StringTokenizer Error when outputting to console

Tags: java, exception, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to use the class `StringTokenizer` to split a character string from a text file, but when I'm running the app, the compiler prints in the Netbeans console the words that I'm splitting but also shows an exception.

This is my code:

```
package Calqfunny; 

import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Files {

public String direccion;

public Files(){

    direccion = " ";
}

public Files(String direccion){

    this.direccion = direccion;
}




public String leerTxt(String direccion){

    String auxiliar = " ";

    try{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccion));
        String temp = " "; //Aqui guardamos el texto del archivo temporalmente
        String banana; //aqui almacenamos 


        while((banana = br.readLine())!=null){
            //se realiza el ciclo mientras que el archivo tenga datos.

           temp = temp + banana; 

        }
        auxiliar = temp;

    }catch(Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\"¿Cómo vas a pedir un archivo que no existe? :v\"");

    }

    String nombre = null, apellido = null, edad = null, bday = null;
   StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer (auxiliar, ";");

    System.out.println("Nombre\tApellido Edad\tFecha de Nac.");
    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){


          nombre = tokens.nextToken();
          apellido = tokens.nextToken();
          edad = tokens.nextToken();
          bday = tokens.nextToken();


          System.out.println(nombre+"\t"+apellido+"\t"+edad+"\t"+bday);

    }

        return auxiliar;
  } 
}
```

This is the output from my app

```
Nombre  Apellido  Edad  Fecha de Nac.
David    Villa     31        1985
Andrea   Pirlo     36        1980
Lionel   Messi     29        1987
Tomas    Rincon    27        1989
```

And this is the exception that the compiler throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)

at Calqfunny.Files.leerTxt(Files.java:69)

at Calqfunny.Mein.main(Mein.java:14)

C:\Documents and Settings\Goyo\Configuración local\Datos de    
programa\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned:1

BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Can you provide your direccion  file content ?

Comment: Like javaguy said, file content would be key to solving your problem. Also, that error is caused likely to your while loop `while(tokens.hasMoreTokens())` - usually hasMoreTokens() is only valid for 1 more token, and you consume 4 at a time.

Comment: @javaguy can you be more specific? i don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop is testing if the `StringTokenizer` has ONE more token. But then you are reading FOUR more tokens. This is going to crash when the number of tokens is not divisible by four.

What you can safely do is:

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(auxiliar, ";");

while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
    token = tokens.nextToken();
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

Comment: so, what can i do? how can check the tokens in my loop?

Comment: You need to first check the existence of the next token (you did that correctly in your while condition) and then read exactly ONE token inside the while loop.

Comment: Ok, in this case i should make one loop for each  token?

Comment: Cool, dude! i understand now. Thank you so much.